# Using Flyway set variable statement throws error

Tags: flyway

**In my EBevar SQL is working well:**

[image]

BUT ....

**Spring boot flyway application runs, it throws an error:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException:
> Migration V1__obsolete.sql failed
> -------------------------------------- SQL State  : 42601 Error Code : **0 Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "@"   Position: 1**
> Location   : db/migration/pgsql/_env/V1__obsolete.sql
> (C:\workspace\t-flyway\target\classes\db\migration\pgsql_env\V1__obsolete.sql)
> **Line       : 1 Statement  : @set TESTINGE = te**
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]   at org.springframe

**I also check with different cases with JDBC.**

CASE 1: I got error when I execute this code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{  
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true","postgres","postgres");  
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("@set TESTINGE = te");

    }

}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
> syntax error at or near "@"   Position: 1     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)    at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:310)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:296)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:273)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:226)
> at com.techgeeknext.MysqlCon.main(MysqlCon.java:14)

[image]

I also checked another way:

CASE 2:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{  
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true","postgres","postgres");  
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SET TESTINGE TO te");

    }

}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
> unrecognized configuration parameter "testinge"   at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)    at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:310)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:296)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:273)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:226)
> at com.techgeeknext.MysqlCon.main(MysqlCon.java:14)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because `@set` is a DBeaver specific command. It‘s not handled on the server but on your DBeaver client.

see DBeaver handbook (https://dbeaver.com/doc/dbeaver.pdf) section Client Side Commands:

> You can use special commands in the SQL scripts. These commands are executed on DBeaver's side, not on the server-side.

If you want to use Variables in Flyway you may want to have a look into Flyway placeholders: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/placeholder